# preventDefault javascript doesnt prevent url redirect

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

My html is

```
<a class="delete" href="/FolderComment/delete/12">delete</a>
```

and my js is

```
$("a .delete").click(function(e){

          //e.preventDefault();   --> tried that too
            var href = this.attr("href");
            $.post(
                href, {},
                function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            );
            return false;
        });
```

but it doesn't work, the page gets redirected.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/PS5hH/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `href` is prepended with #, you should be able to avoid redirection. I have forked your [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeXSa/1/) and added in the selector change from @Alnitak.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector should be `a.delete` - note the lack of space.

As written your callback handler isn't even being invoked because your selector is looking for an element of class `.delete` that's *descended* from an `<a>`, not an `<a>` that *has* that class.

Secondly, for security reasons your browser may not permit links to be hijacked if they're going to a remote resource.

As @NickW has pointed out, a page-local link (starting with `#`) can be redirected.  However, if you want your page to work correctly *without* JS then you may not be able to do that.

A simple fix in that case would be to use JS to rewrite all such links as the page is loaded:

```
$('a[href^="/"]').attr('href', function(index, val) {
    return '#' + val;
});
```